# Unit test insert method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How do you unit test a method that inserts data into the database?

I have a service I'm creating and don't know how to Unit test it.

```
public class EnterpriseDownloadRepository : IEnterpriseDownloadRepository
{
    public int AddFileDownloadEntry(Contract.Data.FileDownloadEntry fileDownloadEntry)
    {
        using (var context = new EFFileDownloadEntryEntitites()) 
        {
            int returnValue =context.FileDownloadEntries.AddObject(fileDownloadEntry);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return returnValue;
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [Unit test insert/update/delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472928/unit-test-insert-update-delete?rq=1)

Comment: This is not a unit test, this is an integration test.

Answer (score 2):

Scott Allen wrote a great [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx) on how to create and use an in-memory double for an Entity Framework context.  It's my go-to pattern for this kind of thing.  (I'm assuming here that your intent is to unit test your repository and not the Entity Framework itself.)